# Programmatically assign users to Azure AD Application using Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to write a script to assign users to an Azure AD application (servicePrincipal) using Graph API. I am testing this in my sandbox, where I have defined the app and assigned users to it.  However, when I query the `servicePrincipal`, I don't see the users anywhere in the response.

**Questions:**

1. Based on the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/serviceprincipal), shouldn't there be `appRoleAssignment`?
2. The documentation says this field is read-only, so how are you supposed to assign users?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the `appRoleAssignments` of a user via the navigation property when querying the Graph API:

```
https://graph.windows.net/tenant-id/users/user-id/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.6
```

You can create assignments by making an HTTP POST to:

```
https://graph.windows.net/tenant-id/users/user-id/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.6
```

The object that you need to send looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "id-of-role",
  "principalId": "objectId-of-user",
  "resourceId": "objectId-of-service-principal"
}
```

**If your app does not have any roles**, but you still want to assign a user, it seems you can just set the id to all zeros:

> Where the resource does not declare any permissions, a default id (zero GUID) must be specified.

So something like:

```
{
  "id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "resourceId": "a27d8321-3dc6-44a1-bf19-2546a9f2806e",
  "principalId": "c4f810b8-2ea1-4580-9595-30275a28c2a2"
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I was trying to see if I could replicate using the newer MSFT Graph API: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/directoryobject  but this is great.

Comment: I am struggling with this. If I get the object id OR the app id of the app, from the tenant, I always get the error resource does not exist

Comment: It's the object id of the service principal you need, not the application. You can find the service principal under Enterprise Applications in Azure portal's Azure AD blade. In its Properties you'll find the object id.

Comment: I keep getting "One or more properties are invalid."... No answer seems to be available anywhere on the internet.

Comment: Make a new question. Comments are for adding input to existing answers.

Comment: @juunas Perhaps  could you check [this question] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66975904/programmatically-assigning-users-to-azure-ad-application-via-graph-api-permiss) please? this is a process to create user role assignments via Microsoft graph API, and it works, but I got an error when recognizing existing roles `'message': 'Permission being assigned already exists on the object'`

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is a bit outdated now.
The URL you need is:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/<tenantID>/users/<userObjectID>/appRoleAssignments
```

Send a HTTP POST with a content of:

```
{
  "principalId": "<objectId-of-user>",
  "resourceId": "<objectId-of-service-principal>",
  "principalType": "User",
  "appRoleId": "<id of role>"
}
```

The easiest way to test is via the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

Or the way im doing it is via  bash script, calling the azure cli

```
cat <<- EOF > roleAssignment.json
{
  "appRoleId": "${UUID}",
  "principalId": "{$USER_ID}",
  "principalType": "User",
  "resourceId": "${SP}"
}
EOF

az rest --method post --headers Content-type="application/json" --url "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/${TENANT_ID}/users/${USER_ID}/appRoleAssignments" --body @roleAssignment.json
```