# How do I programatically assign a user to an application in AD B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am posting an AppRoleAssignment of the following structure to Graph API

```
{
    "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "principalId": "db243e99-61b3-4e42-9359-91ae9bffa715",
    "resourceId": "e4ea7e05-50e7-4f38-b546-bdb6e9b1d77a"
}
```

For resource ID, I first tried the application id, as displayed by the B2C portal. This fails with an error the resource is not found. I got the object id of the application in that tenant, posted that instead, and still got the error resource is not found.

The specific error is
"Resource 'e4ea7e05-50e7-4f38-b546-bdb6e9b1d77a' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present."

How can I add a user to an app in B2C?

Answer (score 0):

From document : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#approleassignment-entity

resourceId is the unique identifier (objectId) for the target resource (service principal) for which the assignment was made.

You could firstly query the service principal object ID by application ID :

```
Get https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/servicePrincipalsByAppId/1062a13d-f7e5-4ea7-8d24-427f6ff1e5e1/objectId?api-version=1.6
```

Then you could assign a user(Where the resource does not declare any permissions, a default id (zero GUID) must be specified) :

```
{
  "id": "id-of-role",
  "principalId": "objectId-of-user",
  "resourceId": "objectId-of-service-principal"
}
```

But if  you want to restrict access if user is not assigned to an application, refer to [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44011681/preventing-access-to-applications-in-azure-ad-b2c) from @Saca , you need to implement that yourself , Azure AD B2C does not currently have first class support for application assignments .

Comment: Any update ? If you have any problem during that, please feel free to let me know