# How to add group or users to Enterprise Apps in Azure using Graph API?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way to add a group or a user to Enterprise Apps in Azure using Graph API ?
Was looking for available properties in Beta and 1.0 but couldn't find this option.

Comment: In addition, there are some other approaches addressing this:
https://gist.github.com/your-azure-coach/65d715aaa9a0fcdc0237b8c98a61279d 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43504824/programmatically-assign-users-to-azure-ad-application-using-graph-api

Comment: https://gist.github.com/garrytrinder/6352326eadbc9d00e808022ec724188e  another approach

Answer (score 4):

To  assign user/group to app using Graph API you could use the below endpoint :

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/appRoleAssignments
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 110

{
  "principalId": "principalId-value",
  "resourceId": "resourceId-value",
  "appRoleId": "appRoleId-value"
}
```

Reference :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

### Parameters

**{id}**- id/upn of the user of the user

"**principalId**" -  id/upn of the user of the user

---

**resourceId** - Id of the app, you can get it from the portal

Azure Active Directory >> App Registrations >> Select All Apps from the dropdown menu >> find your app and click on it.

[image]

---

**appRoleId**

To get the ApproleID

Azure Active Directory >> App Registrations >> Select All Apps from the dropdown menu >> find your app and click on it >> App Roles | Preview

[image]

[image]

Or using Graph

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{id}?$select=displayName, appId,appRoles
```

Comment: Please consider accepting this solution if it had helped :)
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstand, you would like to assign users and groups for an app. And you followed this [Quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/add-application-portal-assign-users) in the portal.

There are three methods to assign or unassign users, and groups, for an app. See here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/assign-user-or-group-access-portal#assign-or-unassign-users-and-groups-for-an-app-using-the-azure-portal

> 1. using the Azure portal
> 2. using the Graph API
> 3. using PowerShell