# Assign an app-role to a managed-identity service principal

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, azure-api-management

Like demonstrated [here](https://dev.to/ib1/protecting-azure-functions-with-api-management-service-53el), I want to secure an Azure Function app with AzureAD and only be able to call/invoke it from an Azure API Management instance (with system-assigned managed identity enabled). This works fine. However I really want to isolate access to the API (Functions app). As it stands now, ANY app in my tenant would be able to successfully authenticate and invoke the API. Therefore, I chose to enable [user-assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/assign-user-or-group-access-portal#configure-an-application-to-require-user-assignment) for that app registration.

So basically, there is 1 API (Azure Functions) that is AzureAD protected. Then there is 1 service calling the API (Azure API Management). Without a role-assignment there is the following error message I can understand.

```
AADSTS501051: Application '<appId>'(<name of APIM managed-identity>) is not assigned to a role for the application '<appId2>'(<name of app registration for the Azure Functions app's EasyAuth feature>).
```

So I created an app role in the API's app registration. The normal guidance on how to assign such a role to an application can be found <strike>here</strike> *(EDIT: WRONG LINK SEE ANSWER)*. However this does only apply to the service principal manually created (read: not a MSI) because this requires the service principal can be found in the portal UI. This is not the case with anything related to a mangaged-identity.

Since the above link also states that assignment can also be done using the [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) I tried this as a workaround.

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/appRoleAssignments
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "principalId": "principalId-value",
  "resourceId": "resourceId-value",
  "appRoleId": "appRoleId-value"
}
```

This does not work yielding the following error response (I have tried appId and objectId for id/principalId/resourceId):

```
"Resource '<guid of principalId>' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present."
```

Do you have any suggestions on what could be done? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43504824/programmatically-assign-users-to-azure-ad-application-using-graph-api/43504909#43504909) answer, the correct way to dit is to use objectIds (which I also tried). The guy answering also [blogged](https://joonasw.net/view/calling-your-apis-with-aad-msi-using-app-permissions) about this, which is exactly what I want to do.... so the approach appears to be valid, still it's not working in my specific case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MS-Graph link in the doc was false. It referred to the assignment of a role to a user, though an application in the linking text body was implied. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) is the correct reference.

> POST /**servicePrincipals**/{objectId}/appRoleAssignments

Also make sure, that in case you have created the Azure subscription with a personal account (eg. outlook.com, hotmail.com) to not use the bearer token of that user in the graph call. Instead create a user in AzureAD, assign proper permissions, and use that account's token.